# Validate SOAP against XSD Schema?

Tags: .net, soap, xsd, asmx, xsd-validation

I have a SOAP web service that was based on an XSD Schema (the schema generated the classes that was used as the input parameter for the web service method), as such:

```
public class CMService : WebService
{
    [WebMethod(Description = "Submit trades")]
    public bool SubmitTrades(List<TradesTrade> trades)
    {
        // Validation, if true, return true, else, return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

How can I validate was passed in against the schema (In this case, the schema class is **TradesTrades**)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've manually validate against the fields instead :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to do this, and may not be worthwhile.

Consider that if the XML being sent to your service doesn't match the schema, then it will not deserialize properly. If it is bad enough, your service operation won't even be called.

That said, if you really need to do this, then you should look at the example of a [SoapExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapextension.aspx) class. I recommend that you first get the example working exactly as-is. Then, I recommend you create a new version of the example, and make it do what you want.

What you want is to modify the WriteInput and/or WriteOutput methods to validate your XML using one of the available methods, perhaps by configuring an XmlReader to do the validation and to read from the input stream; and configuring an XmlWrite to write to the output stream; and then running a loop to read from the input and write to the output.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [XML beans](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/) (xml binding framework) in my previous project. We created the xml schema and then generated the xml beans object from the schema's. These XML beans object have a lot of convenient methods to check the validity of the xml and the values passed in as a part of the XML.

Please let me know, If you have any particular question on XML beans.

Comment: But that was not specified. Sorry, it was a mistake. I got to look at the class to say its .Net.

Answer (score 0):

I been having the same problem myself, the answer is that its possible to do this without needing to manually validate all the fields (which is error prone, plus since you have the schema already you may as well make use of it).

[See this a article on the topic.](http://desalasworks.com/how-to-obtain-soap-request-body-in-c-web-services/)

Basically, the process to follow is to first read the original [Request.InputStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.inputstream.aspx) into an XmlDocument and then apply your schema and validation to the SOAP body inside it.

```
[WebMethod(Description = "Echo Soap Request")]
public XmlDocument EchoSoapRequest(int input)
{
  // Initialize soap request XML
  XmlDocument xmlSoapRequest = new XmlDocument();
  XmlDocument xmlSoapRequestBody = new XmlDocument();

  // Get raw request body
  HttpContext httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
  Stream receiveStream = httpContext.Request.InputStream

  // Move to begining of input stream and read
  receiveStream.Position = 0;
  using (StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8))
  {
    // Load into XML document
    xmlSoapRequest.Load(readStream);
  }

  // Now we have the original request, strip out the request body
  foreach (XmlNode node in xmlSoapRequest.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
  {
     if (node.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && node.LocalName == "Body" && node.FirstChild != null)
     {
        xmlSoapRequestBody.LoadXml(node.FirstChild.InnerXml);
     }
  }

  // Validate vs Schema
  xmlSoapRequestBody.Schemas.Add("http://contoso.com", httpContext.Server.MapPath("MySchema.xsd"))
  xmlSoapRequestBody.Validate(new ValidationHandler(MyValidationMethod));
}
```

Comment: @Steven: I have a number of problems with your code. First, what if there is more than one child of the `SOAP:Body` element? Second, what if there is an element named `Body` but in a different namespace? You would mistake that for the `SOAP:Body` element. Also, it makes little sense to me to create `xmlSoapRequestBody` by re-parsing the inner XML - you've already got an XmlNode, so why not use it? Think in terms of `XmlReader.Create(new XmlNodeReader(node.FirstChild), new XmlReaderSettings{validation settings set})`

Comment: While your points are theoretically possible, seems like you havent used much Soap or Schema validation before. 1) In Soap, you method is the only child of the <soap:Body> element, 2) Its soap, the Body element contains the soap message, while theoretically possible to have a different Body elements in two namespaces this doesn't happen in reality. 3) Schemas apply to XmlDocument items, not to XmlNodes. This code works and it works in 99.9% of situations, thats a good enough number for me.

Comment: @Steven: very wrong about my SOAP experience, BTW, and my first ASMX service validated both incoming and outgoing XML by using a `SoapExtension`. OBTW, what does a SOAP message look like when the input `message` has more than one part?

Comment: Examples please, you're talking edge-case on edge-case.

Comment: Via XMLSpy: `<wsdl:message name="NewMessageRequest"><wsdl:part name="parameter" type="xs:string"/><wsdl:part name="parameter2" type="xs:int"/></wsdl:message>`. Request: `<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><SOAP-ENV:Body><parameter xsi:type="xsd:string">String</parameter><parameter2 xsi:type="xsd:int">0</parameter2></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>`

Comment: Hi John, the example you sent would bomb out in .net anyway, you need an action element (ie `<SubmitInvoices>`) inside your `<SOAP-ENV:Body>` for it to be a valid SOAP request, THEN you can place your two parameters INSIDE this action element. I'll try your `XmlReaderSettings` approach above for schema validation, as I know it can be done that way too (for `XmlDocument`), just not so sure if it can be done for an `XmlNode`.

Comment: @Steven: XmlNodeReader works, as does `XmlNode.CreateNavigator().ReadSubTree()`. Also, "bomb out" in a Document/Literal service, but perhaps not in an RPC/Encoded service?