# XSD with inline namespaces

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

We have a hosted application called Camstar. It provides SOAP webservices built around WCF.

I have a payload that work. I can invoke the web service from SoapUI using the payload below.

```
   <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <WSShopFloorHeader xmlns="http://www.camstar.com/WebService/WSShopFloor">
         <UserName>abc</UserName>
         <Password>def</Password>
      </WSShopFloorHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <Submit xmlns="http://www.camstar.com/WebService/WSShopFloor">
         <serviceData xmlns:ns0="http://www.camstar.com/WebService/DataTypes" ns0:type="LotStart">
            <Factory>
               <__CDOTypeName/>
               <__name>X30</__name>
            </Factory>
            <Comments/>
            <Workflow>
                  <__name>TESTSTOREWF</__name>
                  <__rev/>
                  <__useROR>true</__useROR>
            </Workflow>
            <WorkflowStep>
                <__CDOTypeName/>
               <__name>DBINTSINVSPEC</__name>
            </WorkflowStep>
            <Qty>1000</Qty>
            <Qty2>10</Qty2>
            <Product>
                <__CDOTypeName/>
               <__name>9672-02-9450-D00.BW</__name>
                <__rev/>
               <__useROR>true</__useROR>
            </Product>
            <StartReason>
                  <__CDOTypeName/>
                  <__name>NORMAL</__name>
               </StartReason>
               <Owner>
                  <__CDOTypeName/>
                  <__name>PROD</__name>
               </Owner>
               <Level>
                  <__CDOTypeName/>
                  <__name>LOT</__name>
               </Level>
               <ContainerName>TEST004</ContainerName>
             </serviceData>
      </Submit>
   </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

I am unable to figure out how to create an XSD based on the above XML. The only namespaces are in the Submit and serviceData elements and they are inline.

Also how to create XSLT if I need to generate the name xml from one source to the other?

Comment: you have clubbed two questions! Answers for both questions are totally different and irrelevant to each other!

Comment: @InfantProgrammer'Aravind' can you be a little bit friendly to someone on their very first question, please?  Just focus on the issue - no need for exaggeration and exclamation.  I've found SO to be (mostly) a friendly and helpful community, and I want to preserve and encourage that. If you know the answer to the XSD question, I'm interested to learn.

Comment: @user1860519 Please create a new question for your XSLT issue, and clarify what you're asking about it (e.g. I think "name" may be a typo). SO (and many other things!) work best by doing one thing at a time.

Comment: @13ren, sure.. I regret I went a bit rude, its not really my nature! I was actually preparing answer for both the questions meanwhile .. XSLT I was stuck to take decision whether to write basics or guide him to XSLT tutorial rather..

Comment: @InfantProgrammer'Aravind' I knew you were a good person! :-) I've worked out an answer to the XSD part, but it's based on reading the spec, and so it might be "academic" and not best practice... therefore, I'm very interested to see your answer!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response guys. I am new to all this so please be a little patient with me :) May be I wasn't able to explain my problem as expected.

Comment: Can you please share the answer to the XSD? This is the first problem for me.

Comment: One more question - Is it possible to reverse engineer and create an XSD based on WSDL part?

Comment: @user1860519 I don't know about the WSDL - but no one will see your question way down here in the comments. Please start a new question for that one (actually, try searching first - that might get you an answer much faster).

Comment: @user1860519 I posted my answer about 16 mins ago - maybe you need to refresh your browser to see it?

Comment: @13ren You are right the browser wasn't refreshed. Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. I was wondering how to use 2 namespaces. Your explanation makes lot of sense. I will give it a try. I will start a new question about WSDL. Probably I will search SO before I post that.

Comment: @13ren, I have added my answer.. Well, I have a same answer as yours. ie, linking multiple XSD files using `<import>`

Comment: Are you sure the WSDL doesn't _already_ define the XSD for the data in the messages? It really _should_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer this question in two parts:

**1) XSD for Soap XML:**
Well. Sharing my personal experience.. we get SOAP XML from a third party! SOAP XMLs actually known as WSDL, have bunch of namespace and in our real-time business, these namespace change..

*On the other hand if you treat it as an XML:* 
When you come across XML files that have different namespace for different nodes! I mean, namespace present for parent is not same as that of child nodes.. you would need to comeup with more than one XSD files linked with `<import>` *13ren* has already posted an answer .. BUT!! This kind of validation doesn't work with most of the XML parsers! I myself have experienced!

I have observed it working in MS-visual studio, where multiple assignment of XSD works!.. Where as when you try to load XML and XSD using `XmlValidatingReader` in .Net this fails!! Same behavior with any other online validation tools ..

And there is one more problem with this SOAP XML. They carry bunch of different Namespace, by this method we can't keep on adding as many XSD files as number of Namespace!!

I have also tried .net code that tries to use XSD against Soap XML. [here is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391857/validate-soap-against-xsd-schema)
.. But I am afraid .. I couldn't succeed well!

I give thumbs up to 13ren's method, if you are validating XML manually!

**2) XSLT for an XML:**
XSLT is a functional programming language (not procedural). This is how you go with practicing XSLT:

> First you try copying whole XML as it is .. learn the significance of
>   `<copy> and <apply-templates select="@*|*|text()"/>` pairs .. understand Identity Template!!
>   Notification of attributes by @ and elements by * and text data as
>   text() has to be understood ..
>
> Try to add and remove, elements and attributes ..  use `<template match="element_or_Attribute_name"/>` to remove an element/attribute ..
>   also `<value-of select=""/>` come into picture here ..
>
> Try converting attributes to elments and vice-verse ..
>
> Try moving a group of elements, or a parent tag .. under some other ..
>   use and understand the significance of `<for-each select=""/>` (it would
>   be necessary here ..) ..  also write the code to Rename the tags ..
>   and attributes ..
>
> build a huge XML with different child tag names and grandchild tags
>   Build an XSL which can add and remove lots of tags .. Use all those possibilities
>   which you tried (one at a time) before this

A tutorial for your reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858345/xsltwhich-is-the-best-tutorial-you-would-like-to-recommend

Comment: Yes, I also found that online validation tools can only accept one schema... I think maybe, if you hosted the other schemas elsewhere, and used that URL in the `import/@schemaLocation` it *might* work - but that's really quite  awkward. :) **Re .Net:** I don't use .Net, but I think there *must* be a way to specify multiple schema... ah! XmlValidatingReader has a [Schemas property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlvalidatingreader.schemas.aspx), for a collection of schemas. (NB: it also says it's "obsolete"...)

Comment: @13ren, I remember specifying `import/@schemaLocation` properly! well. I also tried to generate Schema file for Soap XML online using XSD generators. And certainly they generate but they don't work!

Comment: @13ren, And yes .Net doesn't support much .. :(

Comment: BTW: I use xmllint for schema checking, it works for almost everything. http://www.xmlsoft.org/downloads.html  (there's a windows port if you need that).

Answer (score 1):

A schema definition can only define one namespace - so you need to write a separate schema definition for each namespace you need.

Since you have two namespaces (`.../WSShopFloor` and `.../DataTypes` - the "..." is just my abbreviation). you need two schema definitions.

Let's start with the easy one: the schema definition for the `.../DataTypes` namespace.  I've put it in a file names "types.xsd" - this is important for when we `import` it later. The *only* thing it does is define the `type` attribute in that target namespace:

```
$ cat types.xsd
<xsd:schema
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 targetNamespace="http://www.camstar.com/WebService/DataTypes"
>
  <xsd:attribute name="type"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

Now for the schema definition for the `.../WSShopFloor` namespace.  (I won't do all the contents, just enough to address the namespace issues. I'll pretend that the `<Factory>` just has string content, and skip all the elements in it.)

```
<xsd:schema
 elementFormDefault="qualified"
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
 xmlns:ns0="http://www.camstar.com/WebService/DataTypes"
 xmlns:tns="http://www.camstar.com/WebService/WSShopFloor"
 targetNamespace="http://www.camstar.com/WebService/WSShopFloor"
>
  <xsd:import
    namespace ="http://www.camstar.com/WebService/DataTypes"
    schemaLocation = "types.xsd"/>

  <xsd:import
    namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    schemaLocation = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>

  <xsd:element name="WSShopFloorHeader">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="UserName" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="Password" type="xsd:string"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>

  <xsd:element name="Submit">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="serviceData">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="Factory" type="xsd:string"/>   <!-- skip -->
            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:attribute ref="ns0:type"/>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>

</xsd:schema>
```

Firstly, see the import of the `types.xsd` schema definition, and that (at the top), `ns0` refers to the same `.../DataTypes` namespace. Look down further, to the `<serviceData>` element definition, that has a attribute within it that refers to that definition in the that namespace.

Second, we also had to import the soap envelope schema definition. BTW: the schema is actually at the namespace URI, and the parser downloads it. You could also download it, and refer to the filename you gave it (actually, that's what I did - it runs faster without downloading each time).

Just for your interest, have a look at the `.../soap/envelope` schema - it defines top level element `<Envelope>`, and because we import it, our documents can have that as a top level element too.  The `<Envelope>` defines `<Header>` and `<Body>` elements. `<Header>` can contain any content, provided it's in a different namespace ([`##other`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#nsTable)):

```
<xs:any namespace="##other" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="lax"/>
```

`<Body>` can contain any content, at all (`##any` - that is, including those defined in this, the `.../soap/envelope`, schema

```
<xs:any namespace="##any" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="lax"/>
```

The [`processContents="lax"`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#ref33) means it only validates the content if it can obtain the schema - if it can't get the schema, it doesn't give an error. Therefore, to be sure that my schema was actually being used, I deliberately introduced a mistake (e.g. insert a letter in an element name), to see if an error was reported.

---

BTW: I wonder if there is an error in your xml - the `<serviceData>` element has a `ns0:type` attribute, from the `.../Datatypes` namespace. But that is the only thing used from that namesapce... I would expect if the element is marked as a "type", then all its contents from come from that namespace, which would be done with a `xmlns` attribute... so maybe that was omitted?  [Of course, I'm just guessing here - maybe it is correct as is]

*I'm just learning this too, so there might be mistakes or misunderstandings in the above - if anyone sees an error, please correct me!*